# Checking column for value. If true, check same row in another column and count if not blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2003

I have a spreadsheet of employees. Column A is a list of Dept types (sales, HR, payroll, etc). Column B is the date their appraisal is completed, or blank if incomplete.
I would like a function that checks the Dept column for a particular Dept type (e.g. "Sales") and if equals "Sales" then checks the corresponding rows of the Appraisal column and counts how many dates. I would then replicate for all other Dept types. So for the "Sales" example, if there are four employees and two have an appraisal date, the result would be "2". Noting that I don't want it to count the dates in Column B relating to the other Dept types.

Column A -  **Dept**          .      .    .    .    -   HR -    Sales - HR -    Payroll -   Sales - Sales - Sales .

Column B -  **Appraisal** - 1/07/2015 - 8/07/2015 - 6/07/2015 - "Blank" -   "Blank" -   3/07/2015 - "Blank" -

Answer (score 1):

Open the VBA Editor, then choose Module from the Insert menu. Paste the following into the resulting text field:

```
Function DEPTAPPCOUNT(Dept As String, Range As Range, CountRange As Range) As Integer
    Dim count As Integer
    For Each rCell In Range
        If rCell.Text = Dept Then
            If rCell.Offset(0, 1).Text <> "" Then count = count + 1
        End If
    Next
    DEPTAPPCOUNT = count
End Function
```

Press the Save button on the toolbar, then close the VBA Editor to return to your spreadsheet. You can now use the `DEPTAPPCOUNT` function just like Excel intrinsic functions. If your department column spans from A2 to A7 (and the appraisal dates are in B2 to B7 - the counted column must be immediately to the right of the department column for this function to work), enter `=DEPTAPPCOUNT("Sales", A2:A7, B2:B7)` to get the number of sales entries with non-blank appraisal dates. Adjust the first parameter (the `Sales` text) as desired to count in other departments.

If you're on Excel 2007 or newer, you'll need to save the worksheet in the `XLSM` (macro-enabled) format.

For those wondering why `CountRange` must be passed to the custom function even though it isn't used, it's needed to have Excel recalculate the count if the date column is changed. In other words, passing the extra range to the function creates a dependency in Excel's calculations.

Comment: Thanks, but what about when there are more columns than just the two? So if Column A = Dept and Column F = Appraisal. With columns B-E full of data like names, supervisor, etc.

Comment: @Kevin Update the `1` in the Offset call to be the number of columns the Appraisal column is to the right of the Department column. In your situation, you should set it to `4`.

Comment: Thanks so much Ben, it's working now for me. One more thing if you don't mind. I duplicated the formula so that another cell now counts the next column (column G). So I changed the integer to 4 for the first formula, then to 5 for the second formula. I also renamed the second forula to DEPTAPPCOUNT2. This works except that the first forumla recalulates when I update the date field, but the second formula does not. Do you know why this is occurring and do you have a fix? Thanks again.

Comment: Even though the `CountRange` parameter is not used in the code, you need to pass the date cell range in it so that Excel treats those cells as dependencies of the cell containing the `DEPTAPPCOUNT2` call.